# Localize String comparison

Tags: swift, localization

I am trying to compare the strings from searchbar textfield with array of strings. My array is in English strings. I am having localize strings(Burmsese string in localisation file) for the items in the array. I have tried the string method given by apple to compare. Could anyone resolve my problem or this is still mystery and I am wasting my time. I am posting one of the method I have tried, where localized is the custom extension of string for localisation string

```
searchResultList = keyArray.filter {
    return $0.localized.lowercased().contains(ketText.lowercased())
}
```

Comment: What *is* the problem? A *concrete* example of an array and search string, together with expected and actual result, would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Martin, Thank you so much for the consideration. But I resolved it now.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it. If we are using normal contains methods it returns false. But if we are using range, its working perfect for this issue. I have used the following,

```
searchResultList = keyArray.filter {
        guard let _ = $0.keyString.localized.localizedStandardRange(of: ketText) else { return false }
        return true
    }
```